# Struggling to clearTimeout on self invoking setTimeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to query an API every 5 seconds. I build the query with a function, and then use `setTimeout()` to do the 5 second repetition. However in my code, another bit of code can call my function to update the query string, where I want the current timeout to stop, and the new one to begin.

(Chopped down code, also using AngularJS)

```
var timeout;

function queryApi(from, to) {
    var query = '';

    if(angular.isDefined(from) && angular.isDefined(to) {
        // build custom query string
    }
    else {
        // build default query
    }

    $http.get(query).success(function(res) {
        $scope.data = res.data;
    });

    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        queryApi(from, to);
    }, 5000);
}

function customQuery() {
    // Do logic to get custom from & to dates

    clearTimeout(timeout);
    queryApi(from, to);
}
```

The custom query gets cleared, and the new custom query is repeated every 5 seconds, however the original one keeps going on too, why?

Comment: use setInterval() in place of serTimeout()..

Comment: @Ved thanks, but still the same issue

Comment: In queryApi try clearing/stopping the timeout before you set it to a new value. It might be creating a new timer without stopping the original.

Comment: I'd also recommend using the AngularJS $timeout over the setTimeout function: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout

Answer (score 0):

What about adding `clearInterval(timeout)` in the `queryApi` function?

```
var timeout;

function queryApi(from, to) {
    console.log(from + to);
    clearInterval(timeout);
    timeout = setInterval(function() {
        queryApi(from, to);
    }, 1000);
}

queryApi(1,3);
queryApi(5,3);
```